# com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, log4j

I am trying to upgrade to log4j with Spring Boot version 2.6.2. After upgrading I am not able to connect to MongoDB database getting below exception. And my Spring application properties looks like below. If any one would like to help for the solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Using the configuration:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=${MONGO_AUTH_DB}
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_HOST}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${MONGO_PORT}
spring.data.mongodb.username=${MONGO_USER}
spring.data.mongodb.password=${MONGO_PWD}
```

The exception is thrown:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:707) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:415) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:109) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:718) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:576) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This is an extension of the other question that was asked.  Also:  where is the mongo driver core and sync dependency (4.2.3) in the pom?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Due to some compatible versions issues mongo driver core and sync dependency (4.2.3) are removed .But After adding mongo driver core and sync dependency also getting same exception .Could you please suggest to resolve the issue

Comment: A common cause for `Prematurely reached end of stream` is the connection was not using SSL/TLS, but the server was configure to require it, so it immediately closes the connection.

Comment: @Joe I have set the TLS as  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");  MongoClientSettings mcs = mops.  .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                        builder.enabled(true);
                        builder.context(sslContext);

                    })
Can you please check the above syntax and suggest how to fix the issue

Comment: Hi @Rose, were you able to solve this issue? How did you configure mongodb connection over SSL/TLS with a certificate?